# How to set default value for javafx DatePicker in FXML?

Tags: java, datetime, datepicker, javafx-8

Is it possible to initialize default value for DatePicker at FXML level?

```
<children>
            <DatePicker fx:id="datePicker" value="2015-07-20"/>
            <Label fx:id="messageLabel" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" />
</children>
```

Obviously that throws an exception, Is it possibly to call constructor of LocalDate?

For example:

```
        <DatePicker fx:id="datePicker" value="LocalDate.of(2015,07,20)"/>
```

Comment: I realise I could just throw it in controller's initialize, but I wondered if I could populate it at FXML level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you can't populate DatePicker at FXML level, because you can't instantiate an LocalDate object on FXML level because

1. `LocalDate` has no default constructor
2. `LocalDate` has no static `valueOf(String)` method
3. `javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory#getBuilder(LocalDate.class)` returns `null`, meaning there is no builder for LocalDate

Comment: Great answer thanks. I ended up setting in in the controller.

Answer (score 5):

You can set default value of the date to today through controller. Following line worked for me.

```
datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to instantiate java.time.LocalDate from an FXML file, you need to  create and register a custom builder for the class.

1. Create a builder for LocalDate. A builder must implement javafx.util.Builder and its build method. Here is an example of a builder that takes three parameters (year, month, dayOfMonth):

   ```
   package util;
   import java.time.LocalDate;
   import javafx.util.Builder;

   public class LocalDateBuilder implements Builder<LocalDate>{

       private int year;
       private int month;
       private int dayOfMonth;

       @Override
       public LocalDate build() {
           return LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);
       }

       public int getYear() {
           return year;
       }
       public void setYear(int year) {
           this.year = year;
       }
       public int getMonth() {
           return month;
       }
       public void setMonth(int month) {
           this.month = month;
       }
       public int getDayOfMonth() {
           return dayOfMonth;
       }
       public void setDayOfMonth(int dayOfMonth) {
           this.dayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a FactoryBuilder wrapper that decorates the default FactoryBuilder so that it will return your builder when a LocalDate builder is needed. Here is a sample FactoryBuilderWrapper class.

   ```
   package util;
   import java.time.LocalDate;
   import javafx.util.Builder;
   import javafx.util.BuilderFactory;

   public class BuilderFactoryWrapper implements BuilderFactory {

       private BuilderFactory builderFactory;
       public BuilderFactoryWrapper(BuilderFactory builderFactory) {
           this.builderFactory = builderFactory;
       }

       @Override
       public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> klass) {
           if (klass == LocalDate.class) {
               // return our builder
               return new LocalDateBuilder();
           } else {
               // return the default builder
               return builderFactory.getBuilder(klass);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your application's start method, obtain the default FactoryBuilder, wrap it with your wrapper and reassign it to the FXMLLoader:

   ```
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
       loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("myUI.fxml"));
       BuilderFactory builderFactory = loader.getBuilderFactory();
       // wrap the default BuilderFactory
       loader.setBuilderFactory(new    
               BuilderFactoryWrapper(builderFactory));

       Parent root = loader.load();
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
   }
   ```

The following is FXML code to create a Person with a birthDate property of type LocalDate: (You need to import java.time.LocalDate, but not the builder itself)

```
<?import model.Person?>
<?import java.time.LocalDate?>
...
<Person firstName="Jane" lastName="Citizen">
    <birthDate>
        <LocalDate year="1980" month="12" dayOfMonth="19"/>
    </birthDate>
</Person>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for exhausting answer! A bit late but still valuable! +1

Comment: Where is your controller? Where did you define <birthDate> ?

Answer (score 2):

This method returns the current date:-

```
// Date Now  ### "To Date Picker"
    public static final LocalDate NOW_LOCAL_DATE (){
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-  yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date , formatter);
        return localDate;
    }
```

Then call it inside initialize method:

```
datePicker.setValue(NOW_LOCAL_DATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can do something like this if you are implementing Initializable:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", this.locale);
birthDate.setValue(LocalDate.parse(formatter.format(LocalDate.now())));
```